# Power management hook for running scripts on wake

Tags: linux, ubuntu, power-management

I'm looking for a way to run an arbitrary script every time my laptop wakes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put it in /etc/apm/resume.d/  to run on wake up

Comment: I realized that my problem was a little trickier than this, but this is definitely the right answer to the question I asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

add a script to /etc/apm/event.d ?