# Power management hook for running *X11* scripts on wake

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x11, power-management, d-bus

Earlier I asked a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9083/power-management-hook-for-running-scripts-on-wake), but that one was about running system-level scripts.

I have a script that runs a series of `xinput` commands in order to enable two-finger scrolling on my touchpad. It has to be re-run every time the computer sleeps and wakes up again, and it has to be run from within the X11 session. How do I trigger a script to be run on my X11 desktop when the computer wakes up?

P.S. I *suspect* there's a way to do this with DBUS, but I' m fuzzy on the specifics. Maybe someone with stronger DBUS-fu could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting the `DISPLAY` variable for existing X sessions.

Assuming it's `:0`, add the following to the start of your script (well, at least before you run any X-related commands).

```
export DISPLAY=":0"
```

I think you may also need to grant authorization to the local host, by running the following in one of your existing X terminals. (I'm assuming it's you, and only you on this system, if not, this will give other local users access to your X display)

```
xhost +localhost
```

It's been a while since I've really played with X, so hopefully someone can come along and correct me.

Comment: Thanks. I'm hoping there's a different way strictly in user-space - I *suspect* there's a way to do this with DBUS, but my DBUS-fu is not strong enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **`gnome-control-center`** installed, run `gnome-mouse-properties` and visit **Touchpad** tab and click on **Two-finger scrolling**:

[image]

It works very well, and across wake-ups too. So, unless you are using your scripts for something else too, throw them away :)

Comment: Unfortunately, for whatever reason this does not work for my touchpad. The touchpad supports two-finger scrolling just fine, but the GNOME mouse panel shows the option grayed-out. So I have to use a script.

Comment: How about filing a bug (with a patch if you find the code) in Gnome with details of your touchpad model and how it can be set to two finger scrolling so the option can get enabled and other people don't have to hack it with scripts?

Comment: @Caleb: answering to the wrong person?

Comment: That should have been @Avdi, it was in regard to his comment. I would say the best way is to help get gnome fixed so it works instead of inventing ways to hack it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It appears my reading comprehension is impaired, I don't think this will help with the X11 aspect, sorry.

If your system uses the pm-utils package for sleep/wake you can put a script in
/etc/pm/sleep.d/

Here's a script I use to attach my serial mouse after hibernate:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Action script to ensure that serial mouse works
# after a hibernate/suspend
#
# Copyright: Copyright (c) 2009 Michael Vogt
# License:   GPL-2
#

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

SELF=attach-serial-mouse
COMMAND=
IFPLUGD_IFACE=

# pm-action(8) - <action> <suspend method>
#

case "${1}" in
        hibernate)
        # nothing
                ;;
        resume|thaw)
        inputattach --daemon -ms3 /dev/ttyS0
                ;;
esac
```

I saved this as 00_attach_serial_mouse.